# Segfault when trying to index pointer to pointers in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to do something with an array (malloc-ed), namely `arr` of a custom struct. The array is passed by reference to a function. I get a segfault whenever I tried to index anything other than `arr[0]` in the function at runtime (e.g `(*arr[1])->i = 3;`). Why is this happening?

The full source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct{
    int i;
    float f;
}foo;

void doSomething(foo ***arr);

int main()
{
  foo **arr = (foo**) malloc (SIZE * sizeof(foo*));
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = (foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));

  arr[1]->i = 1;
  printf("Before %d\n",arr[1]->i );
  doSomething(&arr);
  printf("After %d\n",arr[1]->i );
  return 0;
}

void doSomething(foo ***arr)
{
  (*arr[1])->i = 3;
}
```

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast the result of `malloc` in C. And: this is no 2D array. (And being a 3-star-programmer is no compliment). And see [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4)

Comment: You get the warning because you didn't put `#include <stdlib.h>` in the top

Comment: @Olaf: How do you pass arr by reference to the function without using 3 stars?

Comment: Why do you thing two stars are not sufficient? (btw: C does not support passing by reference). You are actually passing a pointer to the pointer. What if you nest another function? Do you use four stars?

Comment: @user3886450 Your function does not modify `arr`; it only modifies memory being pointed to (indirectly) by `arr`.  So you may pass `arr` by value to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
(*arr[1])->i = 3;
```

Because the subscripting operator's evaluation [precedes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the dereferencing's evaluation it is equivalent to the following:

```
(*(arr[1]))->i = 3;
```

This is obviously wrong. You need

```
(*arr)[1]->i = 3;
```

therefore.

---

Notes:

- [do not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- add `#include <stdlib.h>` to resolve the warning
- adding an extra level of indirection (`foo***` pointing to `foo**`) is unnecessary; just copy by value
- (in addition to the upper note) a good old 1D array should actually be sufficient in your case
- call `free` after `malloc`

Comment: Adding to this: using `->` with a pointer to an element of an array is a bit confusing, this would be more clearly written as `(*arr)[1][0].i = 3;`, showing that you want to access row 1, column 0 of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you get is because you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`, so `malloc` is not declared, so the compiler assumes it should return `int`. This can lead to all kinds of fun problems. (And you should remove those casts.)

---

The other problem is in this line: `(*arr[1])->i = 3;`

Postfix operators (like `[]`) bind tighter than prefix operators (like `*`), so `*arr[1]` parses as `*(arr[1])`.

You can write `(*arr)[1]->i` instead to fix this, but as it turns out, your function never actually modifies `*arr`, so there's no reason to pass `arr` (the other `arr`, the one in main)'s address to it. Just do this:

```
void doSomething(foo **arr)
{
  arr[1]->i = 3;
}
```

and call it as `doSomething(arr)`.